# Detect changes in Input to execute another function in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have two components (parent and a child), Im sending a custom object with name **project** to the child component and it updates/display just right, but when this change occurs I want to execute another function in the child component. Is it possible to detect when the **project** object gets updated so then I run the function in the child component?

So far I have achieved something with the following code, but Im not sure if this is the right approach.

```
ngDoCheck() {
    if (this.oldVal !== this.project.startTime) { 
        this.theFunctionThatIWantToRun();
        this.oldVal = this.project.startTime;;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the input is a complex object with arrays and different property types. In the code example Im only comparing one property of the object.

Comment: Check out ngOnChange

Comment: What kman said, specifically `SimpleChanges` will give you exactly what you need. Search for that API on the Angular site and there's an example

Answer (score 0):

In your child component:

Implement the `OnChanges` interface, and add the function `ngOnChanges` to your component like this. There you can exactly check which Input parameter has changed:

```
@Input() prop: number;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value
}
```

Reference: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Comment: I did not mentioned that the Input is a object with different types and arrays, so on ngOnChanges nothing happens.

Comment: The change detection should fire on every change. The only thing where it does not fire is when you set `changeDetection` to `onPush` in your component (however, it should still work for Inputs and Outputs). 
Is that the case for your component? If not, can you paste all relevant parts of the code? Hard to tell with those few lines.

Comment: The project object (the one that is the Input in the child) in the parent component has input values binded to its properties, when I change those inputs I want to execute the function in the child. So far it works only if I clone the object using the: this.project = Object.assign({}, this.project)